# Server side HBase pre-processing and Thrift/REST API

Tags: rest, hbase, thrift

I'm going to store csv data in a single HBase column, without breaking it up by dedicated columns for sake of space efficiency and very fast data loading to HBase. One CSV row per key. Example:

Key: identifier_abc 
Column1: 'aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd;eee' 
Key: identifier_gghh 
Column1: 'gh;thj;gn'

Meanwhile I need to develop an HBase client that will operate with Thrift and/or REST API (accessing HBase from non-Java code) and the client does not need the whole bunch of CSV data for a specific key. Instead, it only needs certain fields inside CSV. I.e. field 1, 4 and 29.

Thus I want to build a custom pre-processor for Thrift/REST scanner that would parse CSV inside a column and return only requested fields. Unfortunately I didn't find a way to call custom Java package that implements the pre-processing logic from Thrift or REST.

Any advise would be highly appreciated.